# Suppose $G$ is a group with order $n$. Assume $(n,\phi(n)) = 1$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian group?

Tags: group-theory

I have thought about this question alot. Unfortunately couldn't picture any good path to the desirable result.
Suppose $G$ is a group with order $n$. Assume $(n,\phi(n)) = 1$, So they're relatively prime. Prove that $G$ is Abelian group.
I am looking forward to hearing from you. Any hints, tips, or creative solutions are welcome.

Comment: You should perhaps define $(n,\phi(n))$.

Comment: @Danu I updated the question

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers